# Loader not getting callbacks to update ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager

I have an activity that goes and pulls all the users calendar events from the google calendar, the get inserted into the database fine but the `Loader for the`ListFragment` of the activity never gets the callbacks to refresh the list when there is a change. I have to back out of the activity then come back in for the loader to load everything up correctly.

I have done loaders before and never had this problem, I basically copied the loader from another of my projects that works correctly so I dont under stand why its not getting the callbacks when the content changes?

this is my insert method into the database

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long rowID = db.insert(EVENTS_TABLE,null, values);
    Uri _uri = null;
    if(rowID > 0){
        _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE,rowID);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri,null);

    }else{
        throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
    }
    return _uri;
}
```

as you can see I am calling `notifyChange` so the adapter updates but it does not.

this is my `ListFragment`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){
    super.onActivityCreated(state);

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    View v = getView();
    v.setClickable(true);
    setEmptyText("No Events");
    populate();
}

public void populate(){
    mAdapter = new CalendarRowAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.calendar_view, null,
            new String[] {CalendarProvider.EVENT,CalendarProvider.LOCATION,CalendarProvider.DESCRIPTION,CalendarProvider.START},
            new int[] {R.id.calendarEntryText,R.id.locationEntryText,R.id.descEntryText,R.id.dateEntryText},0);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            CalendarProvider.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {CalendarProvider.ID,CalendarProvider.EVENT,
        CalendarProvider.LOCATION,CalendarProvider.DESCRIPTION,CalendarProvider.START}
    ,null,null,CalendarProvider.START + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);
    if(isResumed()){
        setListShown(true);
    }else{
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

like I said, everything is going into the database correctly, just the loader is not getting the callbacks to refresh the list.

the calendar events are put into the database from an `AsyncTask` but I dont think thats the problem

The logcat shows no errors either

**EDIT**

my query method

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqlBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.setTables(EVENTS_TABLE);

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == 1){
        sqlBuilder.setProjectionMap(mMap);
    }else if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == 2){
        sqlBuilder.setProjectionMap(mMap);
        sqlBuilder.appendWhere(ID + "=?");
        selectionArgs = DatabaseUtils.appendSelectionArgs(selectionArgs,new String[] {uri.getLastPathSegment()});
    }
    if(sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "")
        sortOrder = START + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    Cursor c = sqlBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null,null, sortOrder);
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your insert method you call `notifyChange` with the URI for that specific row that was inserted,but on the query side, the URI is a different URI that represents the entire data set. `notifyChange` on `/foo/bar/1` won't notify listeners listening for `/foo/bar`. So in your `insert()` method you need to call `notifyChange` with the URI for the dataset, rather than the particular row.

Comment: I got burnt by the same thing on my last project.

Comment: weird thing is looking at my other projects with loaders, I have it that way too but it works.....

Comment: @superfell, thanks a lot. I didn't know what `notifyChange` and `setNotificationUri` were used for. My code is not yet tested properly but I think that if I use `content://com.my_provider/my_table` when I insert an item and use the URI as the second argument of `setNotificationUri`, I should use the same URI when deleting the item to be notified